# Как поменять стиль отдельного элемента QTableWidget в PyQt?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt

Необходимо поменять цвет заднего фона в ячейке (1, 1) (либо любой другой) по ходу программы, если цвет фона остальных ячеек задаётся  через `app.setStyleSheet(STYLE_SHEET)`. Приветствуются любые методы:
редактирование самого `STYLE_SHEET` (так, чтобы остальные ячейки не менялись), добавление кода, переход на PyQt6, ...).
Методы `item.setBackground` и `item.setData` работают только если отключить `app.setStyleSheet(STYLE_SHEET)`.

```py
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
class Table(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        # Создание таблицы
        table = QtWidgets.QTableWidget()
        table.setRowCount(4)
        table.setColumnCount(2)
        table.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
        table.setItem(0, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem("00"))
        table.setItem(0, 1, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem("01"))
        table.setItem(1, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem("10"))
        table.setItem(1, 1, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem("11"))
        self.setCentralWidget(table)
        self.show()
        

        # установка цвета фона для элемента (1, 1)
        item = table.item(1, 1)
        item.setBackground(QtGui.QColor(255, 0, 0)) # не работает
        item.setData(QtCore.Qt.BackgroundRole, QtGui.QColor(255, 0, 0)) # тоже не работает



STYLE_SHEET = '''
        QTableWidget::item {
            color: red;
            background-color: #DFD0CA;
            }
        QTableWidget::item:alternate {
            color: red;
            background-color: #DFE0CA;
            }
        QTableWidget::item:selected {
            selection-color: blue;
            background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0.5, y2: 0.5, stop: 0 #FF92BB, stop: 1 white);
            }
'''

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    app.setStyleSheet(STYLE_SHEET)
    ex = Table()
    app.exec()
```

Comment: В C++ `itemAt` и далее `setBackground`. В PyQt должно быть так же.